# Create or update multiple records like first_or_create.increment!(counter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a request in my rails app that needs to create or update a nested record every time a request is made.

```
Model.where(id: 1).events.first_or_create.increment!(:counter)
```

This works fine, but today I need to make the same to a lot of objects

```
Model.where(created_at: start..end).map{|m|
  m.events.first_or_create.increment!(:counter)
}
```

I could call `update_all('counter = counter + 1')` but I can't be sure if every model has an associated event, hence the `first_or_create`

Is there a way improve this call? Bare in mind some requests select more than 5000 records

Comment: If current one is slowing down the response time, then u can push the work to background.